Configure Visual Studio Code formatting to put arguments in Java functions on new lines
I am using VS Code to write Java code.
How can I make it so that the autoformatting puts each argument in a multi-argument function call on a separate line?
I have tried the Java Formatter Settings, but didn't find anything appropriate.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example

an example (before and after code blocks) would be a nice addition, but I find the question quite clear as is.
